# Floating Action Button (FAB) appears in rectangle shape by default - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, material-design

I've been working on a android app which requires FAB. When I try to add FAB it appears rectangle instead of circle. How to get the circle shape by default.

I added the `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0` dependency in gradle

[image: rectangular floating action button]

**fab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ProjectListActivity">

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="32dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:rippleColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Why are you putting `CoordinatorLayout` inside `ConstraintLayout`? Also, set the correct constraint on your `CoordinatorLayout`

Comment: Possibly, you copied it from the [official Material docs](https://material.io/develop/android/components/floating-action-button/) because you're using it with `CoordinatorLayout` as well but showing that, they meant the `RootLayout` which is `ConstrainyLayout `in your case. So, the `CoordinatorLayout` is redundant and unnecessary. Also. you don't have to use `layout_gravity`  so remove that property as well. Now, after removing these two, you have to use `Constraint` `bottom_ToBottom` & `Right_toRight` to set the `FabButton` position, I believe this will fix the issue.

Answer (score -1):

first:Restart Andriod studio
second: make clean project

Comment: The XML for the button still exists in this file, I think he has to remove it